# Spring Injection with annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

How to perform Spring Injection with and `<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.controller" /> <mvc:annotation-driven/>?`

when we use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` then we do not have to specify our bean for controller so how to give ref when we use `<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.controller" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`@Autowire` annotation and define the <\bean> in the Application context.xml

[Here](http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-applicationcontext/) is an example. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSR 330 annotations: `@Inject`. You can also use the Spring specific `@Autowired`, but `@Inject` is better since based on a standard reference. See the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations) for more information.

Example from the Spring documentation:

```
@Inject
public void setMovieFinder(MovieFinder movieFinder) {
    this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
}
```